# Compute average on pandas dataframe with based on another column criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| CodigoCliente | Ene-2021 | Feb-2021 | Mar-2021 | Abr-2021 | May-2021 | Jun-2021 | Jul-2021 | Ago-2021 | Sep-2021 | Oct-2021 | Nov-2021 | Diciembre-2021 | Ceros | Promedio | GM | LM | IC | PromP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cliente1 | 166 | 155 | 166 | 172 | 153 | 162 | 127 | 141 | 158 | 163 | 148 | 147 | 0 | 154.83 | 7 | 5 | G |  |
| Cliente2 | 180 | 147 | 139 | 133 | 138 | 145 | 136 | 149 | 131 | 139 | 107 | 116 | 0 | 138.33 | 6 | 6 | L |  |
| Cliente3 | 57 | 263 | 142 | 146 | 152 | 179 | 159 | 150 | 120 | 164 | 160 | 149 | 0 | 153.42 | 5 | 7 | L |  |
| Cliente4 | 152 | 70 | 103 | 145 | 130 | 140 | 143 | 123 | 125 | 86 | 65 | 68 | 0 | 112.5 | 7 | 5 | G |  |
| Cliente5 | 82 | 70 | 49 | 58 | 45 | 70 | 50 | 51 | 58 | 48 | 55 | 67 | 0 | 58.58 | 4 | 8 | L |  |

I compute the average of the data and columns GM and LM store the number of months that are greater and lower than average, respectively. In the column IC I have a G if GM cell is greater than LM or L if is lower. With this information, I want to fill the column PromP based on IC column. If this cell has a G compute an average only with the months that are greater than average store in Promedio column and if this cell has a L the average is computed only with the months that are lower than average.

The desired result is

| CodigoCliente | Ene-2021 | Feb-2021 | Mar-2021 | Abr-2021 | May-2021 | Jun-2021 | Jul-2021 | Ago-2021 | Sep-2021 | Oct-2021 | Nov-2021 | Diciembre-2021 | Ceros | Promedio | GM | LM | IC | PromP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cliente1 | 166 | 155 | 166 | 172 | 153 | 162 | 127 | 141 | 158 | 163 | 148 | 147 | 0 | 154.83 | 7 | 5 | G | 163.14 |
| Cliente2 | 180 | 147 | 139 | 133 | 138 | 145 | 136 | 149 | 131 | 139 | 107 | 116 | 0 | 138.33 | 6 | 6 | L | 149.83 |
| Cliente3 | 57 | 263 | 142 | 146 | 152 | 179 | 159 | 150 | 120 | 164 | 160 | 149 | 0 | 153.42 | 5 | 7 | L | 130.85 |
| Cliente4 | 152 | 70 | 103 | 145 | 130 | 140 | 143 | 123 | 125 | 86 | 65 | 68 | 0 | 112.5 | 7 | 5 | G | 136.86 |
| Cliente5 | 82 | 70 | 49 | 58 | 45 | 70 | 50 | 51 | 58 | 48 | 55 | 67 | 0 | 58.58 | 4 | 8 | L | 51.75 |

I solved the problem with nested for loops because I confused with where method of pandas. But is too slow. Does anyone have some suggestion about use pandas instructions only?

Answer (score 0):

Use apply!

Write your function and apply your function. You might need lambda for that.

Look here:
https://www.statology.org/pandas-apply-lambda/